# Prevent Child class from accessing protected member variable of "Grandparent" class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class called "Grandparent" with a special protected member variable like:

```
class Grandparent
{
protected:
   MyClass m_obj;
}
```

I have a class "Parent" that derives from this and monitors access to the m_obj member variable with special getters and setters:

```
class Parent : Grandparent
{
protected:
   void setObj(val) { m_obj = val; }
   MyClass getObj { return val; }
}
```

Finally, I have a class "Child" that inherits from Parent and uses those setObj and getObj methods in Parent:

```
class Child : Parent
{
  //some other methods that call getObj and setObj
}
```

My issue is, I want to force the Child class to use the getters and setters in the Parent class, rather than being able to access the m_obj variable in the Grandparent class directly. I do not have privileges to edit the Grandparent class, only the Parent and Child classes. How do I do this?

Comment: Protected data is never a good idea.  Protected should be for an inherited, derived-only _interface_, not data.   So make the data private, and move get/set functions into Grandparent.  Make Parent use getters/setters too and problem solved.  If Parent needs its address, then make it a friend, and make an accessor for the addr, and use the addr accessor--never directly access base data unless it's public and it's basically equivalent to a struct.

Comment: I can't edit the Grandparent class--it's not my code.

Comment: In `Parent` you should be able to change the access specifier of `m_obj` putting it as private, search "c++ inheritance change member access specifier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MatG's comment about searching "c++ inheritance change member access specifier" answered by question. I didn't realize you could change the access modifier of a parent class member in a derived class.

```
class Parent : Grandparent
{
protected:
   void setObj(val) { m_obj = val; }
   MyClass getObj { return val; }
private:
   using Grandparent::m_obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to your own question.  Especially providing an example. It will be really helpful to other people who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the current `Parent` *is-a* `Grandparent` relationship to `Parent` *has-a* `Grandparent` one? You would have the options of [Composition](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/composition/) or [Private Inheritance](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/private.html) to choose from but given that you're having an inheritance between `Parent` and `Grandparent` currently and that `m_obj` is a protected member of `Grandparent`, I'd gather it would be more convenient to just switch to Private Inheritance since you'd still have access to all the public/protected functions/data of the `Grandparent` class as it is. Now with this change, since `m_obj` would become a `private` member of `Parent`, `Child` wouldn't have access to it, and using setters/getters would be the only option for the `Child` to use.